# A/the fear of something

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

What is the reason for using **a** and **the** in the following sentences (taken from Wikipedia):

> **The** fear of the dark is a common fear or phobia among children...
>
> **A** fear of falling, along with **a** fear of loud noises, is one of the most commonly suggested inborn or "non-associative" fears.

The context of both sentences looks exactly the same. Do different articles convey different meanings here? Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score -2):

In the first instance, *the* is used because the speaker means a well-defined (definite) example of 'fear', which they explain with the words immediately following ("*of the dark*").

In the second sentence, I can only guess that there can be more than one fear of falling (same with loud noises), which perhaps justifies the use of the indefinite article.